# itextsharp read password protected file into stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

We have a pdf that we fill out from a web form via iTextSharp 5.5.  We save this pdf to a network share due to a web farm environment.  Later in the application we need to present the filled out pdf to the user for reading only to confirm the document before continuing.

The PDF is password protected, for viewing purposes we get around this with:

```
PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
```

All of this works when on a single web server or localhost development if save the PDF to a folder on the web server and thus read from that local server.
However, when deployed to a web farm and we need to read the PDF back from a network share location, thus, getting the file and reading it to a stream.  However, using this technique we always get the "Enter password to open the PDF".

The PDF is displayed in an iFrame with the following:

```
// DOES WORK (but only on single server or localhost)
// pdfAgreement.Attributes["src"] = "PdfFolder/myfile.pdf";

// does not work
pdfAgreement.Attributes["src"] = "../ShowFile.aspx?file=myfile.pdf";
```

Code in ShowFile.aspx:

```
 string path = "networkshare" + "myfile.pdf"; // Request.QueryString["file"];
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

 if (file.Exists)
 {
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);
   PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();    
   PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms);
   pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
   pdfStamper.Close();
   pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();
   reader.Close();

   Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
   Response.AddHeader("content-length", pdfBytes.Length.ToString());
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=data.pdf");
   Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
}
```

Is there a way to read a password protected file from a memory stream?  For whatever reason this works when on a single web server or local host, but not if we need to read the file from a file share.

Answer (score 0):

So I found that this code works just fine when your page is inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page.

The page I was using was inheriting from a BasePage which does some other magic to the response, which was messing up the Response of the .aspx page.